# How to wrap __getitem__ method correctly to keep square brackets functionality

Tags: python

I have a class B that wraps the the `__getitem__` method of class A:

```
def my_decorator(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Decorator')
        method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print(idx)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()
        self._a.__getitem__ = my_decorator(self._a.__getitem__)

    def get_a(self, idx):
        self._a[idx]


b = B()
b.get_a(0)
```

I would expect the following output:

```
Decorator
0
```

But instead I just get:

```
0
```

If I change `get_a` method as follows, I get the expected behaviour:

```
def get_a(self, idx):
    self._a.__getitem__(idx)
```

It seems that wrapping the `__getitem__` method doesn't affect the access with square brackets. Is there any way to make the original code work with square brackets access? I don't want to modify the implementation of `get_a`.

Comment: You didn't return the value of `self._a[idx]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self._a[idx]` is equivalent to `type(self._a).__getitem__(idx)`, not `self._a.__getitem__(idx)`. The *instance* attribute `__getitem__` you define is ignored by the `[]` syntax.

You need to define a subclass of `A` that overrides `__getitem__`.

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print(idx)


class SubA(A):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print('"Decorator"')
        return super().__getitem__(idx)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = SubA()

    def get_a(self, idx):
        self._a[idx]


b = B()
b.get_a(0)
```

(Just to note: `__getitem__` should really *return* a value, in which case `get_a` needs to explicitly return the value of `self._a[idx]`.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it doesn't work now. The problem is that I don't want to create `SubA` since I have many different classes that need to be wrapped in the same way. I guess I could dynamically create these classes but that complicates things.

Comment: You may need to rethink your design. You can't override `__getitem__` on a per-instance basis. (You might *patch* `A` directly, if `A` allows it, but I wouldn't recommend that, as it would affect *all* instances of `A`, not just those use by `B`.)

Comment: Why do you need to override `A.__getitem__`, instead of putting the desired code directly in `B.get_a`?

Comment: In the real design I have a list of `A` instances (and other classes) inside of `B`. So I really need to override the `__getitem__` of each of those instances. I think I will just use my original implementation which just calls `self._a.__getitem__` since that's an implementation detail that doesn't affect the usage of class `B`. Thanks!

Comment: *Why*? Do you need really need to change how `A.__getitem__` works, or do you just want to do something *with* the value of `a[...]`?

Comment: I want to modify the input of `A.__getitem__`. So instead of receiving `idx` as an input, it will receive something like `data_storage[idx]`. For that I create a wrapper that has a reference to `data_storage` inside. Could I just do `self._a[data_storage[idx]]` inside `get_a`? Yes, that was how it was implemented before, but I prefer the wrapper approach since `get_a` is inherited from another class and I don't want to override it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that in `get_a`, and in fact that doesn't care about the type of `self._a` (as long as you aren't using type-hinting to make the type of `data_storage[idx]` incompatible with the argument type of `__getitem__`).

Comment: I suspect there are all sorts of XY problems associated with your use of inheritance here.